# Missing something simple, program in C wont accept answer?

Tags: c

I am working on this project in C where I want to provide the user with some hourly salaries and once they have selected that choice (by number, 1-4) they will enter in how many hours they worked and in the end the program will calculate how much they earned. However, when it pops up and you enter your chosen number, nothing happens. I know I am missing something verrryyy simple here. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BASEPAY1    8.75    // $8.75/hr
#define BASEPAY2    9.33    // $9.33/hr
#define BASEPAY3    10.00   // $10.00/hr
#define BASEPAY4    11.20   // $11.20/h2
#define BASEHRS     40      // basepay
#define OVERTIME    1.5     // 1.5 time
#define AMT1        300     // 1st rate tier
#define AMT2        150     // 2st rate tier
#define RATE1       0.15    // rate for 1st tier
#define RATE2       0.20    // rate for 2nd tier
#define RATE3       0.25    // rate for 3rd tier

int main(void)
{
    double hours;
    double gross;
    double net;
    double taxes;
    double pay;
    int response;
    double total;
    double num;

    printf_s("************************************************\n");
    printf_s("Pick number from 1-4 based on salary:\n");
    printf_s("\n1) $8.75/hr\n");
    printf_s("\n2) $9.33/hr\n");
    printf_s("\n3) $10.00/hr\n");
    printf_s("\n4) $11.20/hr\n");
    printf_s("\n5) quit\n");
    printf_s("************************************************\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &response);
    while (scanf_s("%d", &response) == 1 && response != 5)
    {
        if (response > 4)
        {
            printf("enter a valid number please\n");
            continue;
        }
        switch (response)
        {
        case 1: pay = BASEPAY1;
            break;

        case 2: pay = BASEPAY2;
            break;

        case 3: pay = BASEPAY3;
            break;

        case 4: pay = BASEPAY4;
            break;

        case 5:
            return 0;

        default:
            break;

            printf("Enter the number of hours: \n");
            scanf_s("%d", &hours);
            total = hours * pay;
            printf("your gross pay this week is: %d", total);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `scanf_s("%d", &response);` which is *before* the loop. Also, `scanf_s("%d", &hours);` → `scanf_s("%lf", &hours);`

Comment: You have two `scanf_s`s consecutively.

Comment: @CoolGuy thank you - still a little confused, do I move the     scanf_s("%d", &response); somewhere else? I put it in the while loop but it doesnt work that way either

Comment: No. Don't move. Just remove the first `scanf_s("%d", &response);`. Leave the other one in the loop itself.

Comment: @CoolGuy I removed it but same issue, I enter in a number, hit enter, and it doesnt accept it, just moves to the next line and I can enter another number :(

Comment: Using good indentation would've helped. You mis-placed the `}` of the `switch`. Also, `printf("your gross pay this week is: %d", total);` → `printf("your gross pay this week is: %f", total);`. Also, note that `case 5: break;` will never be executed. And `if (response > 4)` → `if (response < 1 || response > 5)`

Comment: I have it indented in my program but can't ever seem to keep that indentation on this site, still not used to how to keep that formatting here. That misplaced bracket in the switch was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: ..somethng that you would have spotted for yourself if you had run your code under your debugger:(

Answer (score 2):

You have unreachable code after the `break` in the `default` case.  You want to move that code past the end of the `switch` statement, so that when you `break` from the `switch` it will fall through and execute it.  As it is, that code can never be executed, which is why you're never seeing "Enter the number of hours:" etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
convert default:
        break;

        printf("Enter the number of hours: \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &hours);
        total = hours * pay;
        printf("your gross pay this week is: %d", total);
to 
default:


        printf("Enter the number of hours: \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &hours);
        total = hours * pay;
        printf("your gross pay this week is: %d", total);
        break;
```